# Can't connect to DB2 Driver through Python: SQL1042C

Tags: python, db2, dashdb

I can't connect to a DB2 remote server using Python. Here is what I've done:

1. Created a virtualenv with Python 2.7.10 (On Mac OS X 10.11.1)
2. installed ibm-db using `sudo pip install ibm_db`
3. Ran the following code:

   `import ibm_db
     ibm_db.connect("my_connection_string", "", "")`

I then get the following error:

> Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error
>   occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004 SQLCODE=-1042

I've googled around for hours and trying out different solutions. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a proper guide for setting the environment up on Mac OS X + Python + DB2.

Comment: I have the same problem with environment Linux + Python 2.7 + DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the setup instructions here?
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html

You need your DB2 ODBC driver properly installed before your Python code will work.

This issue may also shed light:
https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/34

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions and I've also read through the issue on GitHub. However, it does not solve my problem. I'm worried that it is relatin to my recent upgrade to OS X El Capitan.

Comment: I agree. The new "system integrity protection" security feature in El Capitan could be the culprit. I can't get the ODBC driver installed either.

Comment: I tried deactivating System Integrity Protection. However, without luck.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to install the driver successfully and connection to db is established without any problem.

The steps are:
1) Upgraded to OS X El Capitan
2) Install pip - sudo pip install
3) Install ibm_db  - sudo pip install ibm_db 
4) During installation, below error was hit

Referenced from: /Users/roramana/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ibm_db.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libdb2.dylib in /Users/roramana/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ibm_db.so with restricted binary

After disabling the System Integrity Protection, installation went fine.

From the error sql1042c, it seems like you are hitting some environment setup issue.
You could try setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path where you have extracted the odbc and cli driver .

If the problem still persist, please collect db2 traces and share with us:

db2trc on -f trc.dmp

run your repro

db2trc off

db2trc flw trc.dmp trc.flw

db2trc fmt trc.dmp trc.fmt

Share the trc.flw and trc.fmt files.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the error 1042C in one of the mac machine.

Solution for the same is to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `clidriver/lib/icc`. I would suggest you set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to both `clidriver/lib` and `clidriver/lib/icc` For Eg:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.6-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/clidriver/lib:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.6-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/clidriver/lib/icc
```

I have python 2.7 installed in my machine and easy_install/pip install auto downloaded clidriver to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.6-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/` directory.

Request you to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as per your environment. Please let us know whether it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**check your ibmdb connection parameters**

```
conn=ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=dbname;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=32286;SECURITY=SSL;SSLSererCertificate=DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt;UID=username;PWD=passwd",'','')
```

conn=ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=dbname;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=32286;SECURITY=SSL;SSLSererCertificate=DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt;UID=username;PWD=passwd",'','')

**Ensure that ssl certificate parameter --*filename with extension***
SSLSererCertificate=**DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt**